# Going back isn't popping navigation corretly with React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

The way I have my set up currently is

Root Navigation

- HomeNavigation ? AuthNavigation (depending on login or not)
- EditProfile
- Profile (ProfileStack)

ProfileStack

- ProfilePage
- ProfileFollowers
- ProfileFollowing
- Setting

The problem I am having is. When I go to the `LandingPage` -> `ProfilePage` (userId 4) -> `Following` then press `navigation.goback()` has not problem. It takes me back to the user page. When I try

`LandingPage` -> `ProfilePage` (userId 4) -> `Following` -> `ProfilePage` (userId 5) -> `goBack()` the result isn't going back to the following listing page but instead back to the `LandingPage`.

I thought within React Navigation it follows a history such that going back results in popping off the current page and going back to the last one we visited. Am I not understanding this part? The way I am going back for my navigation is:

```
return <ProfileStack.Navigator>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfilePage" component={Profile} options={({ route, navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: "Profile Page",
            headerLeft: () => {
                return <Ionicons onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} name="md-arrow-round-back" size={30} color="black" style={{ marginLeft: 15 }} />
            },
            headerRight: () => {
                return <Ionicons onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')} name="ios-settings" size={30} color="black" style={{ marginRight: 15 }} />
            }
        }
    }
    } />
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileFollowers" component={ProfileFollowers} options={() => {
        return {
            title: 'Follower'
        }
    }} />
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileFollowing" component={ProfileFollowing} options={() => {
        return {
            title: 'Following'
        }
    }}/>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="Setting" component={Settings} />
</ProfileStack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the following command:

```
navigation.navigate(Screen)
```

React navigation is such that it stores screens in a stack. So the second cell in your stack is always the page you navigated to the new page. Finally, using the same command, you will have an experience similar to `goBack()`.
React navigation detects that you are returning to the previous page. So there will be no problem.
Of course, there are ways to solve your problem. But for now, this is the fastest way to get there. And there is no wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did try but there is a minor problem with this approach. Lets us use Instagram as an example. We go from a Post to the user page and load all it's info using UserId we send as param. We can goBack() to the post page by just clicking `goBack()`. Now if we did instead Followers and go to another user page meaning the UserId is different, At that point, if we had navigate(screen) when we go back we still need to keep the UserId reference somehow since it'll cause it to crash.

Comment: Unless we start sending an array of userId to keep reference of which one we continue to go back to but it sounds like a loop whole of possible errors. I might be wrong and am trying to wrap my head with this approach to access 3 pages.            LandingPage -> ProfilePage -> Following -> ProfilePage -> Following then needing to go back all of them accurately.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Although its a little confusing and I'll need to create a custom history. It is working correctly. I'll backtrack and try to find a new approach in the future as a todo task. Thank you again for the help